# Is it possible to pass input values from command line to variables in Jest test? (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I hope to implement a function that would allow me to pass input values from the command line and then export those values into my Jest test.

Currently, I have a prompt function that prompts users for their inputs. However, the function will never run -- the test case will always run and neglect the function.

Comment: I hate to answer a question with a question, but why would you want to parse cli arguments in (presumably) a unit test?  One of the purposes of unit tests being you know your inputs and those inputs should have expected outputs.  I think you might be better off mocking the method where the user is prompted for input.  That way you know what the input is before the test is executed.

Comment: Hi @MGM_Squared, thank you for your reply. What do you mean by "mocking the method where the user is prompted for input"?

Comment: @Porshe I'm assuming you have some method that is prompting the user for their input during normal execution of your app.  You could use Jest to spyon that method and return some custom implementation.  

https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: Hi @MGM_Squared, thank you for your response. I tried the Jest Spyon method but the same issue still arises. The jest tests execute without waiting for my method that prompts the user for input to execute finish first.

Comment: I'm sorry to here that, but that is all the help I can really give without seeing some code.  It could be a test setup issue or something to do with order of operations or a package you are using that I'm unaware of. 

I will say your tests shouldn't be waiting for input, it should be providing input in place of the method that prompts for user input.  That would be where the mock comes in.